Has Gambit ever been shown to charge objects without direct contact in the comics?
In the 2024 film Deadpool & Wolverine, there's a scene where Gambit fights the Russian at Cassandra Nova's base. Gambit charges his bo staff and thrusts it into the Russian's chest, causing the Russian's body to charge and then explode. This scene surprised me, as I thought Gambit needed direct contact to charge objects and make them explode.


My knowledge of Gambit comes mainly from the 90s X-Men: The Animated Series and its sequel, X-Men '97. In these shows, Gambit always charged objects (usually his signature playing cards or his staff) by touching them directly with his hands before using them against enemies. The comics I've read seem to depict his powers the same way, leading me to believe that direct physical contact was necessary for his ability to work (hence the fingerless gloves).
I'm curious if the movie's portrayal of Gambit charging objects indirectly has any basis in the comics. Has Gambit ever demonstrated the ability to charge something without touching it directly, such as by using his staff as a conduit?

I'm tempted to try to get some frames of Gambit charging up things without touch them, but as it is not charging things through his staff, I don't know if that would answer your question.

I haven't found an example of him charging something through his staff, but apparently, before Mr. Sinister did brain surgery on him as recounted in Uncanny X-Men Issue #350, he was able to charge items just by looking at them, but he was unable to completely control the power.
New Sun, the Gambit of Earth-9921, who was trained from birth, and never had the surgery, showed the same ability to charge items with energy without having to touch them.
